# Animation list drawable as ImageView drawable source on Android 5

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

Is there a specific reason why the following animation does not play when set as drawable source of an image view under Android 5?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <animation-list android:oneshot="false"   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:duration="750" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_status_battery_0" />
<item android:duration="750" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_status_battery_1" />
<item android:duration="750" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_status_battery_2" />
<item android:duration="750" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_status_battery_full" /> </animation-list>
```

Works perfectly on Android 4.4.

Comment: On 4.4 the AnimationDrawable would start playing whenever the view's visibility changed, even if the animation was stopped or had never been started. On 5 it will only start playing after start() is called.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems that for AnimationDrawable objects that are embedded inside LevelListDrawable objects, there is only the following way to do it on Android 5:

```
LevelListDrawable lld = (LevelListDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Drawable current = lld.getCurrent();

if(current instanceof AnimationDrawable) {
    ((AnimationDrawable)current).start();
}
```